# Can this Flash effect be receated with JS and css?

Tags: javascript, css, flash, html

take a look at the first panel (in red) on the homepage.

http://www.boomtown.co.za/

I'd like to do something like this with an invisible image and only reveal parts of it as the mouse tracks over. Is this possible without using Flash?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible yes, but only in modern browsers (chrome, safari, firefox, opera).

You would need to have two `<div>`'s

like so..

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="revealer"></div>
</div>
```

and CSS like so

```
.container {
    position: relative;
    background: url("images/your-background.jpg");
}
.revealer {
    position: absolute;

    //set the mask size to be the size of the container
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;

    z-index: 1;
    background: url("images/your-background-over-state.jpg");

    //css3 image masks, this is not cross browser, see the demo for 
    // cross browser syntax
    mask: url("images/mask-shape.png") no-repeat;

    //make sure the mask is off screen at first, by setting the mask position
    //to minus the width and height of your mask image
    mask-position: -300px -300px        
}
```

And the JS

```
window.addEventListener('load',function(){
    var background = document.querySelector('.container'),
        revealer = document.querySelector('.revealer');

    background.addEventListener('mousemove', function(e){

        //the minus represents the half the width/height of your mask image
        // to make the reveal centred to the mouse.
        var x = e.offsetX - 150,
            y = e.offsetY - 150; 

        // move the position of the mask to match the mouse offsets     
        revealer.style.maskPosition = x+'px '+y+'px';

        return false;
    });


});
```

Because of the way this works you need to ensure that any other content in the `.container` has a higher z-index than the mask to ensure the content is not masked. To do this add relative positioning to the elements in the container

like so

```
.container *:not(.revealer) {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 2;
}
```

Images used in masks are images where the solid colours create the visible or fill area, and the transparent areas are the mask or cut out.

**[Demo with cross browser code](http://jsfiddle.net/AshMokhberi/2BWxb/)**

Comment: I'd love to fiddle with your code but there's no effect output on jsfiddle?

Comment: what browser are you using? Try it in chrome, I tested in firefox and it seems that it does not support the new CSS property.

Comment: I was on firefox, at home now using chrome and the jsfiddle words smashlingly :) but gods, it's complicated for me right now. thank you though, i'll work on it a bit

Answer (score 3):

This can be done quite easily using some css and background positioning with javascript. Here's 2 examples : http://jsbin.com/ococal/3

The source code is quite easy to understand and you can start working out with this.

Comment: ended up just applying a white box shadow to the border to break the line a bit

Answer (score 2):

You could do it by using a transparent png image that was a radial fade from transparent in the centre to semi-transparent at the edges and making it follow the mouse.

```
document.onmousemove=mousefollower
function mousefollower(e){
  x = (!document.all)? e.pageX : event.x+document.body.scrollLeft;
  y = (!document.all)? e.pageY : event.y+document.body.scrollTop;
  document.getElementById('myImage').style.left = x + 'px';
  document.getElementById('myImage').style.top = y + 'px';
}
```

Obviously you can use jQuery for this too, and set the mousemove function to occur only over a specific div. Also make sure the image you use is large enough (at least twice the size) so that the edges don't show up when you move to the far sides of the div (this means that for large areas you will need a huge image so it may get a big laggy). Put the image in the div and set overflow to none to clip anything that falls outside of the area.

Comment: This won't achieve the same effect. it will only provide a semi transparent circle to follow the mouse. It won't reveal a part of the element behind it.

Comment: This is along the right lines. The transparent png needs to be the one with the intricate design bitten out. Then you need an image _behind_ this that follows the mouse, this image is a fade from white in the centre to red. I suspect there would be a `canvas` way of achieving this too with some clever javascript.

Comment: That would be similar to some of the jquery zoom scripts, yes? If you guys could point out an example I could tinker with, that would be perfect. My JS isn't that ninja yet.

Comment: I can't see how you guys are getting to this conclusion, the method above and the one used in JS zoom scripts is a very different thing to the effect shown in the example.

Comment: The idea was to create a semitransparent circle to follow the mouse. I was thinking that this would allow the colour to show through clearly, whilst dimming the rest of the background